# Can I forgo using an RTC for this circuit if my intent is to set up a clock, a chronometer, a timer for shutdown and PWM LED lamps?

Tags: microcontroller, display, oled

[image]

Here's what I'm going to create (hopefully): An electronic candle with flickering lights (via PWM) that also shows the current time (digital clock), the time transpired since it has been turned on (chronometer) and the amount of time remaining before it shuts down on its own (timer). It will have five push buttons: left, right, menu/enter (it changes depending on whether or not you're on the first screen), return and On/Off.

Full disclosure, I have never done any of this. That is why I want to know if it's possible for me to have each feature (clock, chronometer, timer) working properly without bringing an RTC to the circuit. It's fine if I have to set up the hour each time I turn it on, so long as it works whenever it's on.

The crystal is there to synchronize ATMEGA328P-PU and 128x64 LCD + SSD1306 controller with each other (or so I've read).

Comment: A fine learning project. Consider these mods to your schematic: Add a capacitor with short leads between **VCC** and **GND**. (we usually use 0.1uf). No pull-up resistors appear on **SCL, SDA**. You might be able to use programmable pull-ups inside the processor. If not, add 10k from each of these lines to VCC.

Comment: RTC is mainly used to keep its timer alive when uC is off. You can design an interrupt routine triggered by a non-RTC timer.

Comment: A very nice Schematic, the only I would be concerned about is the missing pull up resistors for the I2C lines. I would add the RTC, you just do not have to install it until you get tired of setting the time. The recommended pull ups for 5V is 4.7K. The program pull ups are shaky at best, however you can turn them on and use pull up resistors.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do all of that without an RTC, so long as you're content to set the time every power-up.

You might find it tricky to keep accurate time, but it's a good exercise.

And it's worther looking at all the lower-power possibilities of the ATMega328, which might mean you can keep it running on your batteries. Basically you put it in a very low power mode, waking up periodically to keep the time up to date, then sleeping again.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is possible. But it won't be accurate the longer it is on and depending on your code. It will drift. Even RTC drift but those drift at seconds per year.

You could add a 32 kHz crystal and use it to keep more accurate time. But you might as well add a simple I2C RTC.

And the 16 MHz crystal is there so you can run the ATMega at 16 MHz. It's not required, you could run it with the internal 8 MHz crystal. It's not as accurate but still works. The LED screen is not dependant on the 16 MHz clock.